# ERROR: OpenSSL Crypto development libraries are not installed properly in required location

Tags: linux, openssl

This case is it.

```
[root@VIDA0 turnserver-2.6.2.1]# ./configure 
install is /usr/bin/install
pkill is /usr/bin/pkill
more is /usr/bin/more
Use TMP dir /var/tmp
Compiler: cc
Do not use -lsocket
Do not use -lwldap32
Do not use -lwldap64
Do not use -lintl
Sockets code is fine: no sin_len field present
relay threads can be used... may be...
Do not use -lcrypto
ERROR: OpenSSL Crypto development libraries are not installed properly in required location.
Abort.
```

and .. done.. install is failure..

What can I do about this? I searched for the error but did not get anything

Comment: What is your distro?

Did you install libssl-dev before compiling?

Comment: A good starting point is usually `configure.log` (or maybe it is `config.log`, it's been a while), which will right near the end have both the source code as well as commands and perhaps also the output that led to it concluding that your build environment has a problem.

Answer (score 9):

Just install the dev package of openssl which will install the headers.

if your OS is Redhat / Centos / Fedora : `sudo yum install openssl-devel`
Ubuntu / Debian : `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`